# What is the difference between logging.fatal and logging.critical?

Tags: python, logging

What is the difference between logging.fatal and logging.critical? Both seem to behave in exactly the same way in Python 3.4. Are both kept because of some kind of backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`logging.FATAL` has been equal to `logging.CRITICAL` from the very first commit of the `logging` package to the Python repository.

It is there for compatibility reasons; the Java `log4j` package (which was one of the key influencers for this module) uses `FATAL` as the highest level, but Python felt the name `CRITICAL` better reflected the situation.

See [PEP 282 *A Logging System*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/), the Python Enhancement Proposal that added the `logging` package to Python:

> The term CRITICAL is used in preference to FATAL, which is used by
>       log4j.  The levels are conceptually the same - that of a serious,
>       or very serious, error.  However, FATAL implies death, which in
>       Python implies a raised and uncaught exception, traceback, and
>       exit.  Since the logging module does not enforce such an outcome
>       from a FATAL-level log entry, it makes sense to use CRITICAL in
>       preference to FATAL.

Answer (score 15):

There is not a different between `FATAL` and `CRITICAL`. They have the same value:

```
import logging

print logging.FATAL
print logging.CRITICAL
```

Outputs:

```
50
50
```

[PEP-282](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/) explains the terminology:

> The term CRITICAL is used in preference to FATAL, which is used by
>       log4j.  The levels are conceptually the same - that of a serious,
>       or very serious, error.  However, FATAL implies death, which in
>       Python implies a raised and uncaught exception, traceback, and
>       exit.  Since the logging module does not enforce such an outcome
>       from a FATAL-level log entry, it makes sense to use CRITICAL in
>       preference to FATAL.